# Calculator Can't have Decimal

Tags: java, decimal, calculator

My code now works for sum, subtract, multiple, divide. 
However it doesn't show the decimal when I put 10.0 and 2.0 or 5.4 and 2. 
How should I change, then it can be used for decimal??

This is my code now.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;


public class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    // instance variables
    JLabel num1Label = null;
    JTextField num1Text = null;
    JLabel num2Label = null;
    JTextField num2Text = null;
    JButton sumButton = null;
    JButton multipleButton=null;
    JButton divideButton=null;
    JButton subtractButton = null;
    JLabel ansLabel = null;

    // constructor
    public Calculator() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());    // set layout (how elements are arranged in window)
        // ****  label:  num 1
        GridBagConstraints layoutCon = new GridBagConstraints();
        layoutCon.gridx = 0;
        layoutCon.gridy = 0;
        layoutCon.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);

        num1Label = new JLabel("Num 1:");
        add(num1Label,layoutCon);   // added label to JFrame


        // ****  text field:  num 1
        layoutCon = new GridBagConstraints();
        layoutCon.gridx = 1;
        layoutCon.gridy = 0;
        layoutCon.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);

        num1Text = new JTextField(20);
        add(num1Text, layoutCon);

        // ****  label:  num 2
        layoutCon = new GridBagConstraints();
        layoutCon.gridx = 0;
        layoutCon.gridy = 1;
        layoutCon.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);

        num2Label = new JLabel("Num 2:");
        add(num2Label,layoutCon);   // added label to JFrame


        // ****  text field: num 2
        layoutCon = new GridBagConstraints();
        layoutCon.gridx = 1;
        layoutCon.gridy = 1;
        layoutCon.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);

        num2Text = new JTextField(20);
        add(num2Text, layoutCon);




        // ****  Sum Button
        layoutCon = new GridBagConstraints();
        layoutCon.gridx = 0;
        layoutCon.gridy = 2;
        layoutCon.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);

        sumButton = new JButton("Sum");
        add(sumButton, layoutCon);
        sumButton.addActionListener(this);  // register sumButton with the ActionListener in Calculator

        // Multiple Button
        layoutCon= new GridBagConstraints();
        layoutCon.gridx=0;
        layoutCon.gridy=4;
        layoutCon.insets=new Insets(10,10,10,10);

        multipleButton= new JButton("Multiple");
        add(multipleButton, layoutCon);
        multipleButton.addActionListener(this);

        // Divide Button
        layoutCon = new GridBagConstraints();
        layoutCon.gridx = 0;
        layoutCon.gridy = 5;
        layoutCon.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);

        divideButton = new JButton("Divide");
        add(divideButton, layoutCon);
        divideButton.addActionListener(this);

        // ****  label:  answer
        layoutCon = new GridBagConstraints();
        layoutCon.gridx = 1;
        layoutCon.gridy = 2;
        layoutCon.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);

        ansLabel = new JLabel("Answer");
        add(ansLabel,layoutCon);   // added label to JFrame  





        // ****  Subtract Button
        layoutCon = new GridBagConstraints();
        layoutCon.gridx = 0;
        layoutCon.gridy = 3;
        layoutCon.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);

        subtractButton = new JButton("Subtract");
        add(subtractButton, layoutCon);
        subtractButton.addActionListener(this);  // register subtractButton with the ActionListener in Calculator

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Sum")) {
            ansLabel.setText("" + (Integer.parseInt(num1Text.getText()) + Integer.parseInt(num2Text.getText())));
        }
        else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Subtract")) {
            ansLabel.setText("" + (Integer.parseInt(num1Text.getText()) - Integer.parseInt(num2Text.getText())));
        }
        else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Multiple")){
            ansLabel.setText(""+(double)(Integer.parseInt(num1Text.getText())*Integer.parseInt(num2Text.getText())));
        }
        else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Divide")){
            ansLabel.setText(""+(Integer.parseInt(num1Text.getText())/Integer.parseInt(num2Text.getText())));

        }
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculator calc = new Calculator();

        calc.pack();    // resizes window (JFrame) so you can see the elements in it
        calc.setVisible(true);   // make window visible
        calc.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //exit program when close window
    }

}
```

Comment: I imagine not parsing them as integers would be a good start.

Comment: Use Double.parseDouble()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use

```
Integer.parseInt(num1Text.getText());
```

which parses a `String` to an int.

With

```
Double.parseDouble(num1Text.getText());
```

you get a double.

Note that you might want to catch the `NumberFormatException`, since you most likley don't want your program to stop on malformed user input:

```
double num1;
try
{
    num1 = Double.parseDouble(num1Text.getText());
} catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
    // either use a default value or give feedback to the user on what he did wrong
    // for example
    num1 = 1;
}
```

If you don't want to print a double value, if only integer values are entered by the user, then you could first try to parse to int, catch the exception (if any) and then parse to double.

---

Another error in your divison line:

```
ansLabel.setText(
    ""+(Integer.parseInt(num1Text.getText())/Integer.parseInt(num2Text.getText())));
```

You do not check if the second parameter is != 0, otherwise you might divide by 0!

To keep your code more readable you might want to create an extra method for parsing a String to a number:

```
private static double parseDouble(String s)
{
    double num;
    try
    {
        num = Double.parseDouble(num1Text.getText());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        // either use a default value or give feedback to the user on what he did wrong
        // for example
        num = 1;
    }

    return num;
}
```

A possible fix for the division by 0 could be:

```
double num1 = parseDouble(num1Text.getText());
double num2 = parseDouble(num2Text.getText());

String command = e.getActionCommand();

if (command.equals("Sum"))
{
    ansLabel.setText("" + (num1 + num2));
} else if (command.equals("Subtract"))
{
    ansLabel.setText("" + (num1 - num2));
} else if (command.equals("Multiple"))
{
    ansLabel.setText("" + (num1 * num2));
} else if (command.equals("Divide"))
{
    if (num2 == 0)
    {
        ansLabel.setText("ERROR: Division by zero!");
    } else
    {
        ansLabel.setText("" + (num1 / num2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`actionPerformed` is parsing its inputs as `int` and operating on them as such.  If you want to use floating-point numbers, try using `double` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing as an integer cannot handle double's or any floating point number (decimal) as such change your actionPerformed to parse double's instead or parse int's:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Sum")) {
        ansLabel.setText("" + (Double.parseDouble(num1Text.getText()) + Double.parseDouble(num2Text.getText())));
    }
    else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Subtract")) {
        ansLabel.setText("" + (Double.parseDouble(num1Text.getText()) - Double.parseDouble(num2Text.getText())));
    }
    else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Multiple")){
        ansLabel.setText(""+(double)(Double.parseDouble(num1Text.getText())*Double.parseDouble(num2Text.getText())));
    }
    else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Divide")){
        ansLabel.setText(""+(Double.parseDouble(num1Text.getText())/Double.parseDouble(num2Text.getText())));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use double data type instead of integer for 4 operations

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
   public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
   {
      if( e.getActionCommand().equals( "Sum" ) )
         ansLabel.setText( "" + ( Double.
                 parseDouble(num1Text.getText() ) + Double.parseDouble( 
                         num2Text.getText() ) ) );
   // etc.
```